# Check if id in string exists in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I really need your help.

I have two lists:

1. A list with mp3 filenames (mp3list):

> "Artist1 - MySongName_id11111.mp3
>
> "Artist2 - SongName_id2231.mp3
>
> "Artist3 - SongWhatever_id1623.mp3

2. A list with ids:

> 11111
>
> 2231
>
> 1623
>
> 4523

Foreach item in the mp3 list i want to check if the mp3 filename contains an id from the second list.

Eg.
If Artist1 - MySongName_id11111.mp3 contains 11111 from the second list, then do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the python's `re` module to extract the digit from song name.

```
import re
for i in list_of_mp3:
    replaced_string = re.sub(r'.+id', '', i)[:-4]
    if replaced_string in idx:
        print(f'{i} is in idx')
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple loop first list and Make Some Conditions and Spliting Strings

```
    for i in artists:
        if int(i.split("id", 1)[1][:-4]) in idlist:
            # Do Any You Want
```

Comment: please flag this as answer if its correct

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in ids:
  for name in mp3list:
    if str(i) in name:
      # do something
```

note that this will `do something` for the same name twice if it happens to have multiple ids in it;

i'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Probably better to not use `id` as a variable name, as it shadows the builtin `id()` function.

Comment: i feel just about 100% certain that that's not going to be an issue here.

Comment: For this specific question, you're probably right.  But it's no extra effort, so you might as well use a name that won't cause future problems for someone else who finds this answer and adapts it to their specific problem.